# Yet another FizzBuzz in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, fizzbuzz

Time for the most original question of the year: writing a `FizzBuzz` in Haskell!

So here is what I came up with:

```
fizzBuzz :: [Int] -> [String]
fizzBuzz xs =
    [fizz x | x <- xs]

fizz :: Int -> String
fizz x
    | mod x 15 == 0  = "FizzBuzz"
    | mod x 3 == 0   = "Fizz"
    | mod x 5 == 0   = "Buzz"
    | otherwise      = show x
```

Then I can call

```
> mapM_ print $ fizzBuzz [1..15]
"1"
"2"
"Fizz"
"4"
"Buzz"
etc
```

My questions are:

- What are obvious awkwardnesses in this code?
- How could I mix `fizzBuzz` and `fizz` so that there's only one function?
- In `fizz`, is it possible to use a string buffer so that I get rid of the `mod x 15 == 0` guard, taking advantage of its redundancy with `mod 3 x == 0` and `mod 5 x == 0`?

Comment: Did you take a look at other [tag:fizzbuzz][tag:haskell] questions, like [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140294/52915) one?

Comment: @Mast I didn't check this particular one - great answers indeed

Comment: "string buffer" isn't really a thing in Haskell. After all, all values are immutable. You're probably thinking of `str = n % 3 ? "Fizz" : ""; str += n % 5 ? "Buzz" : ""; return str == "" ? n.toString() : str;`. But you cannot mutate `str` in Haskell.

Comment: The equivalent of `(n % 3 ? "Fizz" : "") + (n % 5 ? "Buzz" : "")` would work, but you wouldn't get the "otherwise `show x`" part for free.

Comment: @Gurkenglas: Sure, but at that point you're using a binding either way. It's not like you'll type `(if rem n 3 == 0 then "Fizz" else "") ++ (if rem n 5 == 0 then "Buzz" else "")` twice, so there is a `where str = ...` (hopefully). An `Alternative` instance that doesn't concatenate the lists would make that a real one-liner, though. Or a small helper `orElse :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]; orElse [] ys = ys; orElse xs _ = xs`. But then were merely moving lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[fizz x | x <- xs]` is the same as `map fizz xs`, so `fizzBuzz = map fizz`.

You can use `putStrLn` instead of `print` to print strings without quotes.

Using the fact that `map (g . f) = map g . map f`,  you can merge `mapM_ putStrLn` and `map fizz` into:

```
mapM_ (putStrLn . fizz) [1..15]
```

---

Another solution with everything in single function and without `mod x 15`:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_, when)

fizzBuzz :: IO ()
fizzBuzz = forM_ [1..15] $ \x -> do
  let [m3, m5] = map ((==0) . mod x) [3,5]
  when m3 $ putStr "Fizz"
  when m5 $ putStr "Buzz"
  when (not m3 && not m5) $ putStr $ show x
  putStrLn ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like your solution is overly complex, recursion can make this operation simpler:

```
fizzBuzz :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [String]
fizzBuzz [] = []
fizzBuzz (x : xs) 
   | x `mod` 15 == 0        = "FizzBuzz" : fizzBuzz xs
   | x `mod` 3 == 0         = "Fizz" : fizzBuzz xs
   | x `mod` 5 == 0         = "Buzz" : fizzBuzz xs
   | otherwise              = fizzBuzz xs


main = do
   print $ fizzBuzz [1..20]
```

Using two functions to perform this is overkill. Using `(Integral a) =>` in the type signature allows you to apply this function to float's, int's etc